# Where is my output from the ReceiveHTTPFile function in PureBasic?

Tags: json, api, basic

PureBasic adds a JSON library so it can play nice with web stuff.  But I can't  figure out what type of output I am getting from the `ReceiveHTTPFile()` function.

Their documentation is pretty sparse on this subject.

Here is my code.

```
Procedure GetBitminterData()
FireUpNetwork = InitNetwork()

Debug "If the number below is anything other than zero the network library is working."
Debug  FireUpNetwork

URL$ = "https://bitminter.com/api/pool/stats/"
FileName$ = "stats.json"
BitMinterData = ReceiveHTTPFile(URL$, Filename$) ;THIS LINE HERE MEH

Debug URL$
Debug BitMinterData

; Read JSON data from a string
; More importantly parse the bitminter stats.json file from above.

Input$ = BitMinterData
If ParseJSON(#JSON_Parse, Input$)
  NewList Numbers()
  ExtractJSONList(JSONValue(#JSON_Parse), Numbers())

  Debug "---------- Extracting values ----------"
  Debug ""
  ForEach Numbers()
    Debug Numbers()
  Next 
EndIf

EndProcedure
```

Comment: The [documentation](http://www.purebasic.com/documentation/http/receivehttpfile.html) is very clear. "Returns nonzero if the download was successful or zero if not.". If the download failed, you get a zero returned; any other value means it worked. What part of that is difficult to understand? Your code tries to use the return value as input (`Input$ = BitMinterData`), which seems to indicate you think you're getting the file as a result. You're not - the file is on disk, with the filename you provided in `FileName$` (which is also described in the Parameters section of the same doc link).

Comment: In PureBASIC 5.40 https is acepted.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that all http functions in purebasic can't handle "https". I tested it with the latest stable PureBasic 5.31. Try any url with "http" and it will work. Try "https" and it won't work.

There is a libcurl wrapper for purebasic (https://github.com/Progi1984/RWrappers/tree/master/LibCurl) but it's 5 years old and it's not compatible with purebasic 5.31 anymore.

If you just need something "done", you could still download the "curl" binary (http://curl.haxx.se/download.html#Win32) and execute it inside your purebasic application.

Comment: I can confirm that 5.62, the version I have, does handle https:// without a problem.